# Determine difference between empty array and undefined in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I tell the difference between an empty array and a null/undefined value when reading from a MongoDB with Mongoose? Mongoose reads both as an empty array, but in the database I have to work with the meanings of those is a different one.

**Example:**

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

Mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test'); // mongoose
var Demo = Mongoose.model('demo', { names: [String] }, 'demo');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function (err, db) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  var collection = db.collection('demo');

  // insert undefined array with MongoDB:
  collection.insert({}, function(err, status) {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    console.log('direct DB:', status.ops[0]);

    // retrieve with Mongoose:
    Demo.findOne({_id: status.insertedIds[0]}, function(err, doc) {
      if(err) return console.error(err);
      console.log('Mongoose:', doc);
    });
  });
});
```

When I run this code, it results in this output:

```
direct DB: { _id: 56b07f632390b15c15b4185d }
Mongoose: { names: [], _id: 56b07f632390b15c15b4185d }
```

So Mongoose sets an empty array where there shouldn't be one when reading from the database.
I already tried setting name to undefined in post init hook, but it did not show any effect.

Any ideas how I could read this undef as an undef?

Comment: Probably not the answer you want to hear, but the right answer here is to add a separate boolean field to your schema to indicate whatever your null array field is meant to indicate.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose always initializes array attributes to an empty array.

You can check if the `names` attribute exists and if its `length` property is not `0`:

```
if (doc.names && doc.names.length) {
  // Do something if there is at least one item in the names array.
}
```

The check works by short-circuiting:

1. If `doc.names` does not exist, the result is `undefined` which is falsy. This causes the `if` block to be skipped.
2. If `doc.names` exists and is truthy, then the if block evaluates thh length property of `doc.names`. If this length is `0` or doesn't exist, the boolean expression in the `if` block is false and the  `if` block is skipped.

Comment: How could that tell the difference to a non-existing property in the database?

Comment: But  `doc.names` exists *and* ist truthy, despite the fact there is no names property in the database. This is exactly my problem :-)